# Binomial regression in R: lm() with logit, vs glm() with family=binomial

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, binomial-distribution

I am currently learning about GLMs. Suppose my predictor variable generates a number of "successes" and "failures" as the response variable. Naturally I want to model the probability of success as a binomial model.

```
x <- 1:5
y_s <- c(9,6,2,4,1)
y_f <- 10-y_s
```

A generalised linear model fits a linear regression to the logit link function ie.$$\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=\mathbf{X\beta}$$
Using the `lm` function in R gives

```
logit <- function(p) {return(log(p/(1-p)))}
mod_lm <- lm( logit(y_s/(y_s+y_f)) ~ x)
mod_lm$coefficients
# 1.4058816  -0.6291569
```

But using `glm`  with `family=binomial` gives

```
mod_glm <- glm( cbind(y_s, y_f) ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit"))
mod_glm$coefficients
# 1.2626202  -0.5726736
```

I can't seem to understand why these numbers are not the same. There's been several other questions on this site that are somewhat similar (eg. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489651/linear-probability-model-why-do-lm-and-glm-not-give-the-same-results-in-r)) but they're not quite the same. Am I missing something regarding how GLM works in R? Perhaps I am not understanding exactly what the GLM family is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different modeling strategies. Agresti called your first model with log transformation "the transformed-data approach" (Agresti 2015). Let's call the log function, $g$, which could be the link function in GLM or transformation function in transformed-data approach. In the first case (GLM), you model $g[E(y_i)]$, whereas in the second, you model $E[g(y_i)]$. According to Agresti (2015, 6), "with the GLM approach, [model] parameters ... describe effects of explanatory variables on $E(y_i)$, after applying the inverse function for $g$." However, in the data-transformation approach, this is not the case and "the model does not translate to exact information about $E(y_i)$ or the effect of [predictor] $x_{i1}$ on $E(y_i)$." That's why you have different results.

---

Agresti, A. (2015). *Foundations of linear and generalized linear models*. Wiley-Interscience.